# Summing up one column of a table and transferring the sum into another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `addToCart` and I wanted to sum its content namely `foodCal`. After summing up `foodCal` can I put it in a separate table? If I use `SELECT SUM(foodCal) FROM addToCart`, how will I put the SUM in the other table?

BTW I'm using phpmyadmin for managing my tables.

[addToCart table contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVrbM.png)

[2nd Table: calorieTotal (wish to put it here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzaT9.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow , Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, sub-querying on INSERT INTO is supported. In other words, you can use (SELECT something) inside INSERT INTO.

In your case;

```
INSERT INTO calorieTotal (`totalCal`) VALUES ((SELECT SUM(foodCal) FROM addToCart));
```

Comment: Thanks! Big help :)